# Does Beam supports custom delimiter when reading from text file

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have ldif file format and delimiter as empty line

```
dn: uid=12345,ab=users,xy=random
phone: 111
address: someaddress
email: true
username:abc
password:abc


dn: uid=12345,ab=users,xy=random
objectClass: inetOrgPerson
objectClass: top
phone: 111
address: someaddress
email: true
username:abcd
password:abcd
```

I want to write something like

```
data = (p
            | 'Read File From GCS' >> beam.io.textio.ReadFromText('gs://my-ldif.ldiff', delimiter='\r\n')
            )
```

But looks like there is no option to specify delimiter in python. Quoting from official docs, but does not say how to mention delimiters.

```
Parses a text file as newline-delimited elements, by default assuming UTF-8 encoding. Supports newline delimiters \n and \r\n.
```

I see this is present in java and can any one say if python supports delimiter or not?

```
 PAssert.that(p.apply(TextIO.read().from(filename).withDelimiter(new byte[] {'|', '*'})))
   .containsInAnyOrder(
     "To be, or not to be: that |is the question: To be, or not to be: "
       + "that *is the question: Whether 'tis nobler in the mind to suffer ",
     "The slings and arrows of outrageous fortune,|");
 p.run();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct: it is not yet possible in Python.

I found this open feature request ticket: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-12730. This would be a great starter task for someone interested in contributing to Beam!